# How to give a pause in Android ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I want to add some delay to perform a operation in ViewModel. I have tried with `delay` function which works fine also but still I want to know what can be the good solution in this scenario instead of using sleep/delay and handler.

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(800)
            navHostController.navigate(Screens.HOME.screenName)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a reasonable solution, **It is the perfect usage of the `delay` function**.

When implementing a coroutine, utilizing the delay function is a good option for introducing a pause. However, it is crucial to recognize that this method blocks the current thread and may not be the most optimal approach to achieve your objective.

You are only missing the following to switch the threads:

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(800)
}
```